# how to sort and get row number in one MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table of ID Vs Points, I want to return the Rank of the required id according to his points. I am thinking I can do this if i can sort the table ascending according to points then select the row number of the requited id. the problem is I don't know how to perform both operations (sort the table then select row number) in one query.

Note: I am using php prepared statement to perform the query.

any help please regarding how to perform the two operations in one step.

Data Samples:

```
ID     Points
x      12
y      15
w      4 
z      30
```

Required:

```
to return the rank of any ID. example.. Where Id = y --> it returns "2". (the rank in the table)
```

Update

I performed the below code and it sorts the table and gives a rank correctly, my need now is to select the required ID (where ID = x). how to do that?

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT ID, Points, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank From Cars ORDER BY Points DESC;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Pay particular attention on what to do when two rows have the same number of points.

Comment: I have edited the question. thanks. when two rows have the same points it will not affect as I will return the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example help you

```
 mysql> SELECT ID,points, @curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank from gg ,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r order by points;
+------+--------+------+
| ID   | points | rank |
+------+--------+------+
| w    |      4 |    1 |
| x    |     12 |    2 |
| y    |     15 |    3 |
| z    |     30 |    4 |
+------+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: in above example its taking count and then its ranking it try to modify your query as above

Comment: many thanks Mahesh, but I can't understand how did you get the rank by this (@curRank := @curRank + 1) ?

Comment: i have initialy define it as o and for each raw its value increase if you add your query i can help to modify it

Comment: I've added my data set example, if you can help.

Comment: thanks, I used your code and successfully sorted the table and generate the rank, what is missing is to select special ID from the output. how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116484/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-sheriff-said-elahl).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the official ANSI rank function in MySQL using a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.points < t.points
       ) as rank
from t;
```

This can also be done using variables, but it is rather complicated.

Comment: I realy can't understand the how (select 1 + count(*)  from t t2 where t2.points < t.points) as rank will perform my required output but I will try it and feed you back